# Grails is skipping column?

Tags: mysql, grails

I'm new to Grails. When hooking into MySQL, does Grails require me to declare columns of tables somewhere or is it detecting them automatically? The reason I ask is because...

...using Grails/Groovy with MySql database-

Table :

```
restable
id |  description  |  name  |  site_id  |  location_id
```

Grails:

```
def res=Restable.findAll();
```

Enumerating the properties for each returned instance I get properties for 'description', 'name', and 'location', but there is NO property corresponding to the column for 'site'.

**Edit**

I joined the project. There are no domain classes. There is only a mysql-connector library. The plugin doesn't throw any errors and maps almost all the tables and columns correctly. This one appears to be an issue though.

Comment: Post your domain class.

Comment: GORM will not (by default) read any tables or columns from your database.  you would have to map basically the tables as so called domain objects and the columns there to properties of that class.

Comment: Joined a project and that's the issue. No domain classes (not my choice). Just a mysql connector plugin. So the plugin would have to parse the table columns. My problem lies in the plugin somewhere?